# \newcommand with intercalated arguments

Tags: macros

I want to create a command which works like this:

Writing:

> `\w1o2`

Should yield:

> `W^{1,2}o(I)`

I am aware of the parameters use for `\newcommand`, that would work like this:

```
\newcommand{\wo}[2]{W^{#1,#2}(I)}
```

And this would be used by writing `\wo12`
(For example).

But I specifically want to intercalate letters between commands.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `\wo` won't be recognized as `\w{o}` without much ado

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want.

```
\newcommand*\w[3]{W^{#1,#3}#2(I)}
\w1o2
```

Comment: That works for the example provided, but I do not get why it does not when I write, for example, `\wo12`. Also, it does not work if I leave blank one of the parameters, for example if I write  `\w12`.

Comment: Rewrite and clarify in your question, please. It's not clear what you want. What should `\wo12` output? And `\w12`? how does the command know when to stop? If you write `$(\w12)$` how does `\w` know that `)` is not its third argument?

Comment: @D1X: Any news on this?